# Deploying Flask app with PyTorch model on Vercel results in ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE error: How to fix it?

Tags: flask, pytorch, vercel

Vercel ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE error while trying to deploy a Flask app

[image: Image of error in Vercel console]

I get an error while trying to deploy a Flask app:

> `ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE: data is too long

[My flask code](https://github.com/Adi-UA/adi-ss-backend/blob/main/app.py) is really straightforward and exposes only one endpoint to a the [ESRGAN PyTorch image scaler model](https://github.com/xinntao/Real-ESRGAN).

I tried running the webapp locally with `python -m flask run` and it worked. I was successfully able to send and receive the correct images from the endpoint.

I'm not sure if the issue I am running into comes from my Vercel config, which I based off of [this article](https://dev.to/andrewbaisden/how-to-deploy-a-python-flask-app-to-vercel-2o5k). I deployed using the Vercel CLI, so the config JSON isn't in my git repo, but I am pasting it here:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "app.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "app.py"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my FLASK_APP=app in the environment variables